# Bluetooth remote control using android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an android tablet and have an application installed on it... Now i need to control this application on the tablet through my android device... is there a way to do such thing?

Comment: Is it your application that you want to control? What have you tried till now?

Comment: Yes i want to control some features of my own application through bluetooth. Right now i havent tried anything.. I am thinking of implementing this...

Comment: UPVOTE, from me not because you have well written question but you have just gave me an amazing thought for my new launch! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explore this example project by Google

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

see how it works and try to implement your programming skill to transform this chat application to your idea...

How ever I am assuming that you are the author of application which you have desire to control.

happy coding.

EDITED:
Logic structure is simple both application should be able to detect bluetooth and paired(connect) with each other for communication. once you have communication instead of sending message(in chat) you send some information via buttons which will execute some methods on tablet...Just a thought... As if in chat application you can update and add messages to your thread...this application will help you to reach goal. Lot of work though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Sockets, this shouldn't be a problem for you, because the Bluetooth-connection and communication in Android is very much the same. See the [Bluetooth-Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) and Googles "[Bluetooth-Chat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)" example.